# Spaces between equations and Chinese characters in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, equation-editor, chinese, whitespace, mathtype

I am using Microsoft Word 2007. If I insert an equation by pressing `Alt+=` key inside some Chinese document, there will be no space between the equation and Chinese characters. This looks too crowded（中文A+B中文）.

The following image shows the difference between native Equation Editor and MathType Equation Editor. I also tried manually adding spaces between native equation and Chinese character. But these space look too loose.

[image]

How to make Microsoft Word add small spaces between native equations and Chinese characters, just like it does for normal sentences?